# Как в тексте убрать все кроме текста заключённого между символом s= до символа l=

Tags: java, android

Как в тексте убрать все кроме текста заключённого между символами S= до символов L=

Comment: Добавте прямо в вопрос ваш код и пример данных.

Comment: А функции поиска в стркое и извлечения подстроки вас чем не устраивают? У вас же четкие маркеры начала и конца есть.

Comment: Извините, я новичок и только начал потихоньку изучать данный язык. Подскажите куда копать, код выложу завтра. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у вас строка

```
String in = "hello S= abcd L= stack";
```

Как вариант

```
String out = in.replaceAll(".*(S=)", "").replaceAll("(L=).*", "");
System.out.println(out);
```

[На выходе](https://ideone.com/prhBHx)

`abcd`

Comment: Да забыл уточнить символы S= и  L= тоже должны быть удалены. Вывод только текста между ними.

Comment: Спасибо ! попробую завтра отпишусь .

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "...";
text.substring(text.indexOf("S="), text.indexOf("L="));
```